# Do not transform special characters in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, special-characters

I just want to print the original string.

[Case1] I know put "r" before the string can work

```
print r'123\r\n567"45'
>>`
123\r\n567"45
```

[Case2] But when it is a Variable

```
aaa = '123\r\n567"45'
print aaa
>>    
123
567"45
```

Is there any function can print aaa with the same effect like Case1?

Comment: try string.replace

Comment: Put the `r` before the literal, as in case 1: `aaa = r'123\r\n567"45'`

Comment: errr ... the `r'` prefix is for strings, not for `print`.

Comment: The string contents have to be converted, because `aaa` **actually contains** the newline, and **not** the backslash etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The obvious way to make Case 2 work like Case 1 is to use a raw string in your assignment statement:

```
aaa = r'123\r\n567"45'
```

Now when you print `aaa`, you'll get the actual backslashes and `r` and `n` characters, rather than a carriage return and a newline.

If you're actually loading `aaa` from some other source (rather than using a string literal), your task is a little bit more complicated. You'll actually need to transform the string in some way to get the output you want.

One simple way of doing something *close* to what you want is to use the `repr` function:

```
aaa = some_function() # returns '123\r\n567"45' and some_function can't be changed

print repr(aaa)
```

This will not quite do what you want though, since it will add quotation marks around the string's text. If you care about that, you could remove them with a slice:

```
print repr(aaa)[1:-1]
```

Another approach to take is to manually transform the characters you want escaped, e.g. with `str.replace` or `str.translate`. This is easy to do if you only care about escaping a few special characters and not others.

```
print aaa.replace('\r', r'\r').replace('\n', r'\n')
```

A final option is to use `str.encode` with the special character set called `unicode-escape`, which will escape all characters that are not printable ASCII:

```
print aaa.encode('unicode-escape')
```

This only works as intended in Python 2 however. In Python 3, `str.encode` always returns a `bytes` instance which you'd need to `decode` again to get a `str` (`aaa.encode('unicode-escape').decode('ascii')` would work, but it's really ugly).

Answer (score 0):

If what you really want is just to print the original string, instead of prepending an `r` before the literal, you may want to use the python native function [`repr`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#repr). E.g.

```
>>> aaa = '123\r\n567"45'
>>> print repr(aaa)
'123\r\n567"45'
```

which is equivalent in this (exact) case to

```
>>> print repr('123\r\n567"45')
'123\r\n567"45'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using `repr` function in python:

If you are using python 2 then :

[image]

If you are using python 3 then :
[image]